# React stateless components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Let's say I have a component for lists rendering and I can do it in two different ways.

The first one:

```
const renderItem => item => <li>{item}</li>;

const List = ({ items }) => (
  <ul>
    {items.map(renderItem)}
  </ul>
);
```

And the second one:

```
const List = ({ items }) => {
  const renderItem => item => <li>{item}</li>;

  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map(renderItem)}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

What is the difference between these approaches? I mean performance, renderings count, best practice or anti-pattern, etc.

Comment: The accessibility (scope) is different. Performance should be the same. This is just a design decision.

Comment: it seems there no difference

Comment: the only difference is the lexical scope, as mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance wise there will be no difference. The only concern here is regarding  the scoping of the `renderItem`. Since it is enclosed inside `List` in your second example, it's availability is limited to the scope of `List`.

Generally, You would want to make such a component a reusable one. In such a case making it globally accessible makes more sense.